# when I set the value of a cell with google script it gives me an error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use google script to create a series of sheets and set values and formats.
But one of the values that I set gives me an error.
`rangoaescribirsegundo.setValue('=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+iddocatc+'";"'+diaYMesSpanish+'!C'+l+'");Plazas!A:B;2;FALSO);"")');`
This is the error. Formula parsing error.
[image: Error on sheet]

however, if I modify any data the cell is updated and it works.

I have tried with `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` but it does not work

Edit.
I do not understand why people vote negative and do not contribute anything to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem looks to be like you may be mixed up with `"` and `'`.

I would suggest you use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to construct your formula.

So for example:

```js
let name = "Antonio"
let greeting = "Hello"
let message = `${greeting}, ${name}` // OUTPUT: "Hello, Antonio"
```

Basically you use backticks `` ` `` to wrap the string you are building. Then within you can use a combincation of `"` and `'` no problem, but more powerfully, you can add in `${expression}` and anything inside the curly brackets will get evaluated.

```js
`${5 + 5}`
```

Will give

```js
"10"
```

```
` Hello, ${name}, this is how you might use template literals`
```

Will give

```js
" Hello, Antonio, this is how you might use template literals"
```

Another thing you might try to debug it is to log the resulting string from your formula construction and then manually copy and paste it to make sure that it is valid.

#### EDIT

I just noticed that you are using `setValue`

You need to use [`setFormula(formula)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setFormula(String)) or else the value will be input as a string. This is why the it becomes a formula when you refresh the value.

So it needs to be:

```js
rangoaescribirsegundo.setFormula('=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+iddocatc+'";"'+diaYMesSpanish+'!C'+l+'");Plazas!A:B;2;FALSO);"")');
```

Comment: outch, i dont now this function!  setFormula(formula) . Thanks, I'm going to try it right now

Comment: Thanks its fine now, i change this too.
      var formula = `=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${iddocatc}";"${diaYMesSpanish}!C${l}";Plazas!A:B;2;FALSO);""))`;

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from

```
"'+diaYMesSpanish+'!C'+l+'"
```

Try instead

```
'\''+diaYMesSpanish+'\'!C'+l+'
```

Comment: not rule. =SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12asd32ddEXAMPLEcas12";"1 de mayo");Plazas!A:B;2;FALSO);"") It only works if I make some modification and undo it